# What's wrong in this network topology?

Tags: computer-networks, network-topology, network-analysis

> What are the six mistakes that were made in the configuration of the following network?
> [image: topology]

I could only find 3. Since the subnet on the left has `192.168.10.33` as HostMin and `192.168.10.38` as HostMax, `Host A4` and `Host A5` cannot be in this subnet. `Subnet A` should also have the IP `292.168.10.0` because it's a network address.

I can't seem to be able to find the other 3, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a quick overview, I can find the following problems:

1. The IP address `192.168.10.32` for interface `eth1` of the router is the network address for Subnet A `192.168.10.32/29`. While this generally works, there are some really ancient RFCs that prohibit the use of network addresses for hosts. Typically, the address of a router is either the first or the last host address in a network, in this case either `192.168.10.33` or `192.168.10.38`.
2. The same applies to the IP address `192.168.12.0` for interface `eth2` of the router, which is the network address of Subnet B `192.168.12.0/23`. Traditionally, the router address would either be `192.168.12.1` or `192.168.13.254`.
3. The IP address `192.168.13.0` for interface `eth0` of the router is within Subnet B `192.168.12.0/23`. Presumably, this is supposed to be the upstream interface to the rest of the world and would thus be in some public subnet, a DMZ, a transit subnet, or maybe an RFC 3021 Point-to-Point /31 subnet.
4. The EUI-48 MAC address of Switch B `00-11-27-82-H3-E6` is not a valid hexadecimal number representation. Hexadecimal number representation only uses the symbols `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`, `a` / `A`, `b` / `B`, `c` / `C`, `d` / `D`, `e` / `E`, and `f` / `F`.
5. The IP address `192.168.10.39` of Host A4 is the broadcast address for Subnet A `192.168.10.32/29`. Broadcast addresses must not be used for hosts.
6. The IP address `192.168.10.40` of Host A5 is outside Subnet A `192.168.10.32/29`.

Comment: Thank you! Is subnet A having the IP-address 292.168.10.32 and not 292.168.10.0 (ending in zero) not considered a mistake? I thought network addresses should end in 0 to indicate that they're network and not host addresses.

Comment: @Karla: I don't follow your question. 192.168.10.32 *does* end in zero.